# How to use jquery or javaScript to select an item and click OK to put the item in the input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello everyone~ I am a beginner in programming, and I am completing a task today! But I have some difficulties~
I hope everyone can help me. My English is not very good, but I try to describe my problem completely!

Expected effect

1. Click the input box to pop up the window
2. Click the item, the selected item will have a yellow background, and then press confirm to put the selected item in the input input box, and then the pop-up window will disappear.
3. If you click cancel, the original options will be kept, and the pop-up window will disappear.

However, I just learned jquery recently. I don't know how to implement click confirm and put the item in the input, and how to click cancel to keep the original item and pop out of the window.

Hope you can get help here, thank you again for watching.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.input_box').on('click',function(){
    $('.sport').css('display','block');
  })
  
    $('.sport').click(function(e){
    if(e.target.classList.contains('sport')){
      $(this).css('display','none');
    }
  })
  
  $('.sport').click(function(e){
    if(e.target.classList.contains('sport')){
      $(this).css('display','none');
    }
  })
  
   $('.item').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  })
  

// How to rewrite this program
  $('.confirm').on('click',function(e){
    // only a little change here
    const val = e.target.getAttribute("value");
    $('.input_box').val(val);
    $('.sport_content').trigger("click");
  })
  
});
```

```css
.input_box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.sport {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.sport_content {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}
.sport_content .title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 800;
}
.sport_content .category {
  display: flex;
}
.sport_content .category .item {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.sport_content .category .active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.sport_content .footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.sport_content .footer .cancel {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.sport_content .footer .confirm {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="">Choose your favorite sport</label><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Put in your favorite sports" class="input_box">

<div class="sport">
  <div class="sport_content">
     <h2 class="title">Aerobic exercise</h2>
     <ul class="category">
       <li class="item" value="RUN">RUN</li>
       <li class="item" value="SWIM">Swim</li>
       <li class="item" value="bicycle">bicycle</li>
     </ul>
    
    <h2 class="title">Strength training</h2>
     <ul class="category">
       <li class="item" value="weightlifting">weightlifting</li>
       <li class="item" value="Stand up">Stand up</li>
       <li class="item" value="Barbell">Barbell</li>
     </ul>
     <div class="footer">
       <button class="cancel">cancel</button>
       <button class="confirm">confirm</button>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no big differents between one and multi.hope you can learn it by youself

```js
$(function(){
  $('.input_box').on('click',function(){
    $('.sport').css('display','block');
  })
  
    $('.sport').click(function(e){
    if(e.target.classList.contains('sport')){
      $(this).css('display','none');
    }
  })
  
  $('.sport').click(function(e){
    if(e.target.classList.contains('sport')){
      $(this).css('display','none');
    }
  })
  
   $('.item').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  })
  

// How to rewrite this program
  $('.confirm').on('click',function(e){
    // still only a little change here
    $(".sport").trigger('click');
    var texts = ""
    $(".item.active").each(function(idx,item){
      texts += $(item).attr("value")+" "
    })
    $(".input_box").val(texts)
  })
  
});
```

```css
.input_box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.sport {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.sport_content {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}
.sport_content .title {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 800;
}
.sport_content .category {
  display: flex;
}
.sport_content .category .item {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.sport_content .category .active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.sport_content .footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.sport_content .footer .cancel {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.sport_content .footer .confirm {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="">Choose your favorite sport</label><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Put in your favorite sports" class="input_box">

<div class="sport">
  <div class="sport_content">
     <h2 class="title">Aerobic exercise</h2>
     <ul class="category">
       <li class="item" value="RUN">RUN</li>
       <li class="item" value="SWIM">Swim</li>
       <li class="item" value="bicycle">bicycle</li>
     </ul>
    
    <h2 class="title">Strength training</h2>
     <ul class="category">
       <li class="item" value="weightlifting">weightlifting</li>
       <li class="item" value="Stand up">Stand up</li>
       <li class="item" value="Barbell">Barbell</li>
     </ul>
     <div class="footer">
       <button class="cancel">cancel</button>
       <button class="confirm">confirm</button>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you~
This is the effect I need, but how can I click cancel to keep the original selected item and close the pop-up window?

Comment: Hello @WEIA! for the cancel button effects, you can do it:
`//for cancel button to disapear pop-up window
  $(".cancel").on('click', function(e) {
   $(".sport").trigger('click');
  });`